# PHP isset() function misfiring

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with PHP's isset function. It's often and mysteriously (to me) misfiring.

For instance, when I have a variable that can be either a string or an error array, I try using isset to see if the variable contains one of the known indexes of the array, like so:

```
$a = "72";
if(isset($a["ErrorTable"]))
    echo "YES";
else
    echo "NO";
```

This bad boy prints YES all the way on my server. I tried it on Ideone (online interpreter thingie. It's cool!) here: http://ideone.com/r6QKhK and it prints out NO.

I'm thinking this has something to do with the PHP version we're using. Can someone shed some light into this?

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Comment: You're welcome: http://3v4l.org/f9fNp

Comment: @PeeHaa: Please post that as an answer so that future readers can see it without relying on an outside site.

Comment: *always* use brackets for code blocks. Even (and especially) for one liners. You will thank in less expected moment

Comment: @PeeHaa You rock. Also, I'm switching to 3v4l.org!

Comment: @PeeHaa OMG, thats PHP for you...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the following piece of code:

```
$a = "72";
var_dump( isset($a["ErrorTable"]) );
```

You're checking if `$a["ErrorTable"]` is set. PHP first typecasts any non-numeric offset to `int` and this makes `ErrorTable` equal to `0`.

Essentially, you're just doing:

```
if ( isset($a[0]) )
```

Strings in PHP can be accessed an array, and `$a[0]` is definitely set and the condition will evaluate to `TRUE`.

However, this weird behavior was fixed in PHP 5.4.0 and the  [changelog](http://php.net/isset) for `isset()` says:

> **5.4.0** -- Checking non-numeric offsets of strings now returns FALSE.

Your server is probably using an older version of PHP and that would explain why it outputs `YES`.

---

You can use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) instead:

```
$a = "72";
if ( is_array($a) && array_key_exists('ErrorTable', $a) ) {
    echo 'YES';
} else {
    echo 'NO';
}
```

The output will be `NO` on all PHP versions.

Comment: Any phpdoc link for this info? Would be great to get fully described answer for this issue. ;)

Comment: The question is why it seems to work since PHP 5.0.0 while phpdoc says it's since PHP 5.4.0. ;>

Comment: shouldn't the version be `> 5.4.0`

Comment: `Checking non-numeric offsets of strings now returns FALSE.` .. Didn't know that..

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the empty function like:

```
$a = "72";
if(!empty($a["ErrorTable"]))
     echo "YES";
else
     echo "NO";
```

Answer (score -1):

$a[0] is a way of referencing the 1st character in the string, which is the value "7". Because string characters are simply referenced by their numeric value, the "ErrorTable" is typecast to an int (0)

This is the case in PHP 5.2.17 and 5.3.23, but not in 5.4.15 or 5.5.0