# Undefined Index in php array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Looking to get a count of particular key=>values in an multi dimensional array. What I have works i.e. the result is correct, but I can't seem to get rid of the Undefined Index notice.

```
$total_arr = array();

foreach($data['user'] as $ar) {
     $total_arr[$ar['city']]++;
}

print_r($total_arr);
```

Any ideas? I have tried isset within the foreach loop, but no joy...

Comment: Possibly related: [PHP `isset()` function misbehaving](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17330752/1438393)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$total_arr = array();

foreach($data['user'] as $ar) {
    if(array_key_exists($ar['city'],$total_arr) {
        $total_arr[$ar['city']]++;
    } else {
        $total_arr[$ar['city']] = 1; // Or 0 if you would like to start from 0
    }
}    

print_r($total_arr);
```

Comment: Correct answer. And if one wanted this a little bit “shorter”, one could also mis-use the ternary operator slightly, and replace the whole if/else construct with simply `isset($total_arr[$ar['city']) ? $total_arr[$ar['city']++ : $total_arr[$ar['city'] = 1;`

Comment: `isset` is usually always faster than `array_key_exists` and you'll never have to bother about `NULL` values here, so go with `isset` instead.

Comment: Strangely enough, replacing 'array_key_exists' with 'isset' produces the same undefined index error. Thanks for the solution ogres!

Answer (score 3):

PHP will throw that notice if your index hasn't been initialized before being manipulated.  Either use the `@` symbol to suppress the notice or use `isset()` in conjunction with a block that will initialize the index value for you.